# How to Resolve issue of ValueError of Matplotlib - X and y should be of same size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
X = np.array(data[['x1','x2']]), 
y = np.array(data['y'])
```

When I tried to run `plt.scatter(X,y)` I got the ValueError that X and y must be of same size.

X's Shape is (100,2)
y's Shape is (100,)

What should I do to get a scatter plot?

[This is the Code and the Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBnxG.png)

[New Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybNE2.png)

Answer (score 1):

try;

```
X = np.array(data[['x1','x2']]), 
y = np.array([data['y'], data['y']]).reshape(-1,2)
```

at the moment it doesn't know what to plot on the y for the second set of data.

if you're working from a dataframe, you could do;

```
ax = df.plot.scatter(x='x1', y='y')
df.plot.scatter(ax=ax, x='x2', y='y')
```

Comment: X = np.array(data[['x1','x2']]),  y = np.array(data['y'], data['y']). By doing this I get the same error that X and y must be of same size and by using the dataframe I get a normal plot whereas I want a scatter plot.

Comment: had missed [ ] for the first bit and a reshape, and added scatter for the df plot

Comment: Sorry, But I did not got your point. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: if you see the updated answer, i have added the function for the scatter plot with pandas, df.plot.scatter(...., and i had also not correctly formed the y array, this has also been updated. does it work?

Comment: No it didnt work. Although I got a Scatter Plot but it was not in the way where I can use any algorithm for classification. It was plot. Please see my question for the output I got. The fig is labelled as new output.

Comment: your question was how to make a scatter plot with that data input, and you can now do this, correct? if you're having issues with your classification then make a new question.